# PHP operator ->

Tags: php

I have a php login that works fine in Google Chrome. However when I try to run it in Firefox or IE I have problems when I write the `->` operator, the next code it's interpreted like html code and it's printed in the browser.

Example:

```
<?php

session_start();
$captcha = new SimpleCaptcha();

// OPTIONAL Change configuration...
$captcha->wordsFile = 'words/es.php';
$captcha->session_var = 'secretword';
$captcha->imageFormat = 'png';
//$captcha->lineWidth = 3;
//$captcha->scale = 3; $captcha->blur = true;
$captcha->resourcesPath = "../../lib/resources";
```

The browser print all code after the first "->".

It's very strange because in Google Chrome works fine.
Thanks in advance.

New Information:
The extension of my file is ".php" and the server that I use is Apache from XAMPP.

Comment: What is the extension of your PHP file? Is your server configured correctly to interpret PHP?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, regardless of which browser calls the script. If this script runs in Chrome, then it will not output PHP code in FireFox, unless you've got some very freaky server configuration that handles PHP files differently based on user agent (very, very unlikely).

Comment: Ann, are you certain it works fine in Chrome? It might be worthwhile to do a "View Source" in each browser and compare the output (if you haven't already).

Comment: I've checked the code with "View Source" and compare with the different browsers. I found in Firefox that the tag <?php it's closed with the ->. Maybe it's a problem of the server configuration but I don't understand why in Chrome works correctly :(

Answer (score 3):

View the source of your page. You'll find that it has nothing to do with the `->` and everything to do with your server not evaluating PHP. It will be sending the entire document down, as you've written it, and everything from `<` in `<?php` to the `>` in `->` will be interpreted as a tag by the browser.

You need to figure out why your server isn't configured to run .php files through PHP.

Comment: Except when Chrome.. ;)

Comment: My <?php tag it's closed with the -> instead of ?>. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Yes: "You need to figure out why your server isn't configured to run .php files through PHP."